# Simulate an user click to have an element appear in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Hi,

I have a javascript functions that can only run if certain element is present in the DOM. This element wont be there unless the user clicks a couple buttons. I want to do it so the elements appear anyway.

The ID of the element the user has to click is

```
topcmm-123flashchat-main-toolbar-message-type-option
```

if they click it, the element with the ID below will appear

```
topcmm-123flashchat-menu-style-topcmm-4
```

finally, if they click it, the element below will appear

```
topcmm-123flashchat-toolbar-style-send-sound-btn
```

is there any way to do this? How is it called?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element and trigger a click event in it. See the code below.

```
var l = document.getElementById('topcmm-123flashchat-main-toolbar-message-type-option');
//click on the first element
l.click();
//click on the second element
document.getElementById('topcmm-123flashchat-menu-style-topcmm-4').click();
```

Comment: thanks but seems like the page freezes because the elements appear on screen quite a the same time. Is there any way to make them appear only within the document without showing them on screen?

Comment: On click handler, when you append your new element, you can set the style `display: none;` then, the element appended will be hidden.